# PySpark: read multiple .xlsx files from dir and merge to one spark data frame

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

**I'm trying to get all .xlsx files from a specific directory into one PySpark data frame.**

- The schema is the same for all .xlsx files

What I came up with:

```
directory = os.listdir('/Users/UserName/Documents/excel/')
pattern = '(.*.xlsx)'

for file in directory:
    if re.match(pattern, file): # get only .xlsx files
      pdf1 = pandas.read_excel(file, sheet_name='Analog Voltage Input') #pandas data frame
      pdf2 = pandas.read_excel(next(file), sheet_name='Analog Voltage Input')
      sdf1 = spark.createDataFrame(pdf1) #spark data frame
      sdf2 = spark.createDataFrame(pdf2)
      msdf = sdf1.union(sdf2) #merged spark data frame
```

I know the part in the loop is not working for several reasons but i hope you get the idea.

I'm looking for a function like:

```
msdf.append(spark.createDataFrame(file))
```

Answer (score 0):

@Felix Bartschi ,pyspark (and scala) supports reading csv files directly into a spark dataframe. You can do like

```
df = spark.read.csv('root/folder1/folder2') # folder 2 will contain all your files
```

Refer the documentation below for full usage :

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=csv#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv

Note : Be sure to check the document of the spark version that you are using

Comment: Thanks @Raghu
The problem i have is, that my source files are saved as .xlsx files and not .csv files.
I could run a loop with pandas and convert every file to .csv but i feel like there should be a pyspark solution for this?!
Since Pandas runs in memory and Spark on disk i would lose some of its advantages.

Comment: Ok, now I get it.. What is the problem in your union ?

Comment: I just want to load a bunch of .xlsx files from a directory in a convenient way in to **one** Spark Data frame. 
Something like:
df = spark.read.xlsx('root/folder1/folder2') #But this does not exist in PySpark